# queryIntentActivities() causes nullPointerException for some apps

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-activity

### Background

I've created an app that needs to get info of other apps' supported intents (for example in order to create a shortcut on the desktop) .

### The problem

I'm using the next simple code , which worked fine for me on 99% of the apps i've tested on:

```
final Intent mainIntent=new Intent();
mainIntent.setPackage(packageName);
final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos=getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent,0);
```

The problem is that on some apps (like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) which has the package name "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad" ) , it causes nullPointerException (on the last line of code) .

Btw , the reason I'm not putting extra filtering flags is because I do want to get all of the possible ones , and then present the user a choice - either use the default ones, or try out the others which might not work well.

### What I've tried

Even though the code I've written worked perfectly for all kinds of apps , I've tried to add some flags , for example :

```
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

or:

```
final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos=getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

or both.

### The question

Why do I get this exception only for this app , and how can I fix it and do get all of the supported intents that i can launch it?

Of course I can add the two methods of getting the intents (using try-catch) , but maybe there is a more "correct" way to do so.

I know that I can add the action to the intent of "Intent.ACTION_MAIN" , but this also removes a lot of the possible intents that I wish to get.

Comment: "or try out the others which might not work well" -- and which may not work in the future, or may not even *exist* in the future. The best case scenario is that you get a bunch of one-star ratings. The worst case scenario is that *other developers* get a bunch of one-star ratings because they change things about their app, that work for all normal people, but will break your "shortcuts". "The problem is that on some apps...it causes nullPointerException" -- use LogCat to examine the stack trace associated with your exception, then look at the Android source code to determine the root cause.

Comment: The app is targeted at power users and developers , so they should know what they are doing . About the exception , of course i can search there , i just asked if it's a known issue that anyone else has noticed.